# Dynamic way to add Reactive Forms Validators in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I was reading through the Angular 2 cookbook on dynamic forms using the Reactive Forms module (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html)

I notice that they define how to create the form controls dynamically such as :

```
    questions.forEach(question => {
  group[question.key] = question.required ? new FormControl(question.value || '', Validators.required)
                                          : new FormControl(question.value || '');
});
```

This seems great to begin with, but what would be the best approach to do this if you have multiple or custom Validators?  For example, if I had an existing form control that got defined as

```
this.myForm= this.formBuilder.group({
        inputField:   [this.myObject.inputValueField, [Validators.required,Validators.minLength(4),
            forbiddenValueValidator(5000)]]
    });
```

So in this instance, I would have an input that is required, has a minimum length of 4 and cannot equal 5000, enforced by a custom validation function.

Sorry if there are any duplicates like this, but I couldn't find anything that really pointed to solving a dynamic/metadriven approach to multiple validators with instantiating new FormControl

EDIT:

Here's my potential idea for the fix:

I do think I have it figured out now though, roughly it's like this:

```
validations = {
    required: true,
    minLength:true,
    customCalls: [forbiddenValueValidator(5000)]
};

    let myValidators = [];
    if(this.validations.required) {
        myValidators .push(Validators.required);
    }
    if(this.validations.minLength) {
        myValidators .push(Validators.minLength(4));
    }
    if(this.validations.customCalls && this.validations.customCalls.length > 0) {
        for (let customCall of this.validations.customCalls) {
            myValidators .push(customCall);
        }
    }
```

the validations object could be another part of the json metadata representing the questions data, and the rest can be a quick function that just creates the array for validators.  Then the creation for the control would just look like this:

```
 group[question.key] = myValidators.length > 0 ? new FormControl(question.value || '', myValidators)
                                      : new FormControl(question.value || '');
```

Comment: what do you mean by "Dynamic"?

Comment: Basically that we can define what validators to use via metadata like how they had been defining the forms in the dynamic forms example in the Angular cookbook.

Comment: I have this roughly figured out, I'll add it as an edit to the question